# how to check if a type is defined or not?

Tags: c++, typedef

For example

```
typedef float Real;
```

And want to check if Real is defined or not? For macro, it is easy

```
#define Real float
#ifndef Real
#define Real float
#endif
```

How about typedef?

Comment: Will it always follow the pattern `if (not typedefd) typedef float Real;`, or do you plan on doing something else besides typedefing it?

Comment: I have a feeling this is another XY question, X is your actual problem, you think Y is the solution (check if something is typedefed). Why wouldn't `Real` be typedefed in your situation?

Answer (score 2):

Any `typedef` can be repeated (with the same definition), so you don't need to check if it already exists.

Caveat: old versions of g++ didn't quite following the standard's rules. The solution then, for the particular problem at hand then, was to generate probably unique identifiers.